# Is it OK for an answer to not work from time to time if the language it's written in is probabilistic?

Tags: discussion, policy, answers

If an answer is written in [a language that *deliberately* prevents the programs written with it from doing the same output/calculations/etc. every time by introducing randomness](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Category:Probabilistic), should it be deleted anyway?

Answer (score 6):

## No, it is not OK

If allowed, in an hypothetical probabilistic language that simply executes a random program without even looking at its source code, the empty program would be a solution to all code golf challenges.

On top of that we already reached consensus that [all answers must work with probability 1](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8379/12012), for every possible input.

Comment: "Probability 1" is even still too loose - we require that *every* possible (valid) input results in a correct output. A solution could have an infinite set of inputs that work and a finite set of inputs that don't, and would still have probability 1 of working.

Comment: Good point. I should have said probability 1 for every possible input.

Comment: An answer with probability 1 can still be incorrect for every possible input. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC That distinction is only meaningful if you execute the program an infinite number of times.

Comment: @Dennis A simple example: Print nothing and halt. Then write a program to quit with 1/2 probability in an infinite loop.